Efficient synchronization of TABLE or MATERIALIZED VIEW
I have a Postgres database with several schemas, each containing an identical items table. Initially, these tables were in separate databases, with a master table kept up to date with a kafka queue. Now, all tables are in the same database, so I want to create a unified table or view where I can query across all the items tables as if they were a single table.
I initially attempted creating a VIEW that acted as a UNION of all tables:
CREATE VIEW all_items AS
  SELECT * FROM schema1.items
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM schema2.items;

This approach works, but saw significant performance issues on COUNT() and WITH RECURSIVE.
I then tried using a MATERIALIZED VIEW. After running ANALYZE, this resolved the performance issue I was having on my queries. However, running REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW just takes too long on a database of my size, and wouldn't be able to keep things synchronized fast enough.
What other approaches could I take towards this problem? Could I instead create a table as a union of the other tables, and keep it updated as rows in the other tables change? Or is there a better way of keeping a materialized view synchronized than refreshing the whole thing?

Without seeing the actual statements and their EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output, it is hard to give an answer. But you should definitely use UNION ALL rather than UNION if you want good performance.

Is there a reason why you need three different tables? Would it be possible to have one single table, and give each application (user) the rights it needs to that table?

Even if the tables currently have the same column types and order, don't use SELECT * across UNION: there is no guarantee that those conditions will always hold.

@LaurenzAlbe My main issue is that running REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW takes too long to complete. I can't provide a query plan, as it is a utility statement.

It is very likely the defining query that takes too long. You can generate an execution plan for that.
